# C# ErrorProvides - allow lose focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

I am implementing an Error Provider in a C# WinForms app. By default, when the form opens, a textbox that has a validating method is on focus and I can't switch focus to any other control in the form, including the 'Cancel' button that I have.

```cs
private void TxtUsername_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
        e.Cancel = true;
        errorProvider.SetIconPadding(control, 5);
        errorProvider.SetError(control, "Required field");
}
```

What I am actually trying to add is the possibility to click the Cancel button while textbox is still on focus (i.e. to close the form), but it doesn't let me due to the Error Provider that is present there.

Is there a way to implement this in the app or the only way to do it is by removing the Error Provider?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: It appears you're mixing up the [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) and the Validate events, using the latter, in practice, as input error control. You don't need to set `e.Cancel = true`. That's very annoying (for the User and for you). Use these tools to help you build an Error handler of a higher level. One that is aware there are input errors, provides visual clues and notifies when User action is needed. No action is needed  if the input is canceled.

Comment: The Validating event is raised when you change the focus.  So trying to change the focus while the focus is changed is not likely to come to a good end.  If you set e.Cancel = true then it always goes back to the control whose Validating event you failed.  This should be correct.  You *can* change focus, but you have to do it later.  Easily done by using this.BeginInvoke().  But Validating will be raised again, and you'll fail it again, so that is unlikely to put you ahead.  If you use ErrorProvider then you don't really need e.Cancel.